# Efficient way to update a table with subquery

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

Consider the following data in the table of `books`:

```
bId    serial            
  1       123            
  2       234            
  5       445
  9       556
```

There's another table of `missing_books` with a `latest_known_serial` whose values come from the following query:

```
UPDATE missing_books mb 
SET latest_known_serial = (
  SELECT serial FROM books b 
  WHERE b.bId < mb.bId 
  ORDER BY b.bId DESC LIMIT 1)
```

The aforementioned query produces the following:

```
bId    latest_known_serial
  3                    234
  4                    234
  6                    445
  7                    445
  8                    445
```

It all works, but I was wondering if there's any more performant way to do this as it actually hits big tables.

Comment: maybe you can share also missing books table, and result of 'show create update.... '

Comment: @OzanSen They're actually that simple; only the `bId`s have `unique` constraints and are non-`null`able `unsigned bigint`. Other fields are simply `null`-able `unsigned bigint`.

Comment: If you have at least 10.2, consider using `OVER(PARTITION BY ...)`.

Comment: @RickJames Could you please elaborate, or provide a sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can make performance increase by using indexes to make your query faster: I tried to simulate your query:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN UPDATE missing_books mb 
    -> SET latest_known_serial = (
    ->   SELECT serial FROM books b 
    ->   WHERE b.bId < mb.bId 
    ->   ORDER BY b.bId DESC LIMIT 1);
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                                          |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | UPDATE             | mb    | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   10 |   100.00 | NULL                                                           |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | b     | NULL       | ALL  | bId           | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    5 |    33.33 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1); Using filesort |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see in the above query, It uses a full table scan (type: ALL) to perform the operation: Optimizer didn't select to use the indexes (unique) defined on bId column.

Now Let's make it Primary Key instead of unique index, then run the optimizer to see the result set:

Drop Unique index first:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE books DROP INDEX bId;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Then Define PK on bId Column

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE books 
       ADD PRIMARY KEY (bId);
```

Now test again:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN UPDATE missing_books mb  SET latest_known_serial = (   SELECT serial FROM books b    WHERE b.bId < mb.bId    ORDER BY b.bId DESC LIMIT 1);
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | UPDATE             | mb    | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |   10 |   100.00 | NULL                             |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | b     | NULL       | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    1 |    33.33 | Using where; Backward index scan |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see in the key column, optimizer used the PK index defined on books table! You can test the speed by making small adjustments.